# Cartesian product of a field as a ring extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I'm currently working through an abstract algebra text book on my own, and I'm stuck on this problem that has no solution given:

> Let $K$ be a field, and $0 \neq a \in K$. We define $L := K^2$ with
>   the following set of operations:
>
> $(x,y) + (x^\prime, y^\prime) := (x + x^\prime, y + y^\prime)$
>
> $(x,y) * (x^\prime, y^\prime) := (xx^\prime + yy^\prime a, xy^\prime + x^\prime y)$
>
> This defines a commutative ring structure with one over $L$, with $0_L = (0,0)$
>   and $1_L = (1,0)$.
>
> Please show that the following holds true:
>
> $L$ is a field $\Leftrightarrow$ $\not\exists b\in K : b^2 = a $

How do I approach this? I assume I have to check the properties that cause a Ring $R$ to become a full field, but I'm just stumped here.